# ORA-29548: Java system class reported: could not identify release specified in classes.bin

Tags: java, oracle, xa

Problem: During simulation of distributed transactions using Java and Oracle XA, while starting a new transaction (xa.start) hitting exception "ORA-29548: Java system class reported: could not identify release specified in classes.bin"

Initial analysis: Checked the versions of system JDK and JDK version in Oracle. There is a mismatch.

```
System JDK (Java -version): 1.6.0_31
Oracle JDK (DBMS_JAVA.GET_JDK_VERSION()): 1.6.0_37
```

Is the difference in JDK a reason for "**could not identify release specified in classes.bin**" error? Is there any other potential cases which can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you've got a developer who did a build with `1.7` (or `1.8`) and didn't set the compliance level to `1.6`. I say that because your error is actually from the JRE and the relevant part of the exception is "Java system class reported: could not identify release"

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. Found a solution in link http://surachartopun.com/2013/11/db12c-ora-29548.html. By using update_javavm_db.sql given by Oracle, the version mismatch got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have applied a recent PSU or java patch to your database make sure you have ran the @postinstall.sql.  For example 20406220 has a postinstall.sql in Oracle_home/sqlpatch/20406220 directory.